# Increase size on file storage

Tags: c#

I am making an API request and as a response I am getting an XML. And I want to store the XML in an file on local storage on my Windows Mobile.

```
if (isWriteFile)
{
     byte[] fileData = new byte[8 * 1024];
     Stream ToStream = null;
     if (File.Exists(strXMLResponseFileName))
     {
         File.Delete(strXMLResponseFileName);
     }
     ToStream = File.Open(strXMLResponseFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
     int count = 1;
     while ((count = resStream.Read(fileData, 0, fileData.Length)) != 0)
     {
         ToStream.Write(fileData, 0, count);
     }
     ToStream.Flush();
     ToStream.Close();
     outputXml = XmlReader.Create(strXMLResponseFileName);
}
```

Some times as the XMl response is too big. My file breaks and the XML writing is partially stopped.

Is there a way to increase my file size? I.e `byte[] fileData = new byte[8 * 1024];`.

Comment: Read in chunks and write in chunks, so you're not storing all the data in your memory at once.

Comment: I will try this way .